# Throttling promise execution (API requests, etc)

Tags: timer, typescript, promise

I was working on a client for a remote api and realized that I needed to throttle requests at a maximum rate of 4 Hertz (4 requests per second). I wrote a simple typescript class to do it and wanted to solicit code review. It basically should accept a `() => Promise<R>` and return a `Promise<R>` that resolves once executed by the queue.

My prototype solution is here, and I'd just like to solicit feedback for it. Original code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/throttled-promises-3pscr).

```
/**
 * Request throttle has an add() method which takes a () => Promise<string>
 * and queues the promise to be executed in order.
 * add() returns a promise that resolves with the original promise result.
 */
class RequestThrottle {
  stack = [];
  spacing = 1000;

  add: (req: () => Promise<string>) => Promise<string> = req => {
    let executor;
    const requestPromise: Promise<string> = new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
      let localExecutor = () => {
        resolve(req());
      };
      executor = localExecutor;
    });

    this.stack.push(executor);
    return requestPromise;
  };

  pullAndExecute = () => {
    const op: () => Promise<string> = this.stack.shift();
    // if (op) console.log("throttle found:", op);
    if (op) op();
  };

  interval = setInterval(this.pullAndExecute, this.spacing);

  stop = () => clearInterval(this.interval);
}

const throttle = new RequestThrottle();

/** 
 * Promise tester - to add a bit of extra async operations
 * (eg a network request to an api)
 * */ 
const addChild: (c: number | string) => Promise<string> = count => {
  const list = document.getElementById("list");
  const node = document.createElement("LI");
  node.innerHTML = count.toString();
  list.appendChild(node);
  const promise: Promise<string> = new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      log(`added "${count}"`);
    }, 500)
  );
  return promise;
};

const log = (s: string) => {
  const list = document.getElementById("log");
  const node = document.createElement("pre");
  node.innerHTML = s;
  list.appendChild(node);
};

addChild("Starting a List").then(console.log);

const enqueue: (i: number | string) => () => Promise<string> = i => {
  console.log("enqueueing " + i);
  return () => {
    return addChild(i);
  };
};

for (var i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) {
  throttle.add(enqueue(i)).then(console.log);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important advice I can offer is to turn on `strictNullChecks` and `noImplicitAny`. Without these settings, TypeScript's ability to warn you about problems in your code is severely limited.

Doing this first, TypeScript reveals several problems (Ignoring errors from your tests, you just need a `!` assertion):

```
test.ts:19:21 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

19     this.stack.push(executor);
                       ~~~~~~~~

test.ts:24:11 - error TS2322: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<string>'.

24     const op: () => Promise<string> = this.stack.shift();
             ~~
```

None of these errors are particularly difficult to fix. First, we need to define the type of `stack`. Right now, as it is assigned `[]`, the inferred type is `[]` (an empty tuple). If we look at the type of functions added to it in `add`, we see that a function of type `() => void` is added, so declare that.

```
class RequestThrottle {
  stack: (() => void)[] = [];
```

This change will change the reported errors slightly, giving us more useful error messages.

```
test.ts:19:21 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.

19     this.stack.push(executor);
                       ~~~~~~~~

test.ts:24:11 - error TS2322: Type '(() => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<string>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<string>'.

24     const op: () => Promise<string> = this.stack.shift();
             ~~
```

The next problem is caused by `let executor;`. Since no type has been declared, TypeScript will implicitly type the variable as `any`. You *could* fix this by typing `executor` as `(() => void) | undefined` and then asserting that it has been set after executing the promise, but it is simpler to just add the function to `stack` within the promise.

At the same time, declaring the `add` function as a property instead of an arrow function on the class (like you did with `pullAndExecute`) is kind of weird. I'd prefer this style:

```
class RequestThrottle {
  stack: (() => void)[] = [];
  spacing = 1000;

  add = (req: () => Promise<string>): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
      this.stack.push(() => {
        resolve(req());
      });
    });
  };
```

This resolves the first issue, the second issue can be easily resolved by dropping the erroneous `Promise<string>` type on `op` in the `pullAndExecute` function.

```
class RequestThrottle {
  stack: (() => void)[] = [];
  spacing = 1000;

  add = (req: () => Promise<string>): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
      this.stack.push(() => {
        resolve(req());
      });
    });
  };

  pullAndExecute = () => {
    const op = this.stack.shift();
    if (op) op();
  };

  interval = setInterval(this.pullAndExecute, this.spacing);

  stop = () => clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Next we must consider the access level of each member. `add` should obviously be public. Similarly, it makes sense for `stop` to be public. But `stack`, `spacing`, `interval` and `pullAndExecute` are all implementation details. Users of this class shouldn't need to care (or even know) that they exist. They should all be marked as `private`.

Despite this... users might want to be able to specify `spacing` when using the class. There are two ways to meet this need. Either let the user specify it in the constructor, or add a `start` method that starts the interval. I prefer the `start` solution.

```
class RequestThrottle {
  private stack: (() => void)[] = [];
  private interval = 0;

  add = (req: () => Promise<string>): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
      this.stack.push(() => {
        resolve(req());
      });
    });
  };

  private pullAndExecute = () => {
    const op = this.stack.shift();
    if (op) op();
  };

  start = (spacing = 1000) => {
    this.stop();
    this.interval = setInterval(this.pullAndExecute, spacing);
  };

  stop = () => clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Note that in the `start` method I call `stop` first. This is to ensure that we don't have multiple `queue` consuming clocks running at once.

Now, you mentioned that you wanted this class to work with a `Promise<R>`. As written, it will only let you use `Promise<string>`. Thankfully, this is a trivial fix, we just need to make the `add` method generic.

```
  add = <R>(req: () => Promise<R>): Promise<R> => {
    return new Promise<R>((resolve) => {
      this.stack.push(() => {
        resolve(req());
      });
    });
  };
```

With all these changes together, the class becomes:

```
class RequestThrottle {
  private stack: (() => void)[] = [];
  private interval = 0;

  add = <R>(req: () => Promise<R>): Promise<R> => {
    return new Promise<R>((resolve) => {
      this.stack.push(() => {
        resolve(req());
      });
    });
  };

  start = (spacing = 1000) => {
    this.stop();
    this.interval = setInterval(this.pullAndExecute, spacing);
  };

  stop = () => clearInterval(this.interval);

  private pullAndExecute = () => {
    const op = this.stack.shift();
    if (op) op();
  };
}
```

A couple other notes:

1. Don't use `for .. in` to iterate over arrays. Use `for .. of` instead.

   ```
   for (const i of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) {
     throttle.add(enqueue(i)).then(console.log);
   }
   ```
2. Don't make promises that can never be resolved or rejected. In `addChild`, the promise will never be resolved.
3. Should `RequestThrottle` throttle based on promise starts or promise resolves? Currently it throttles based on the initial call of a function... but if that function takes more than `spacing` to resolve, you could have multiple promises waiting at once. This might be desired, but it is something to consider.

Comment: Can I ask what you meant about needing a `!` assertion? I'm not familiar with this.